# How to document friend injection functionality with doxygen?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, argument-dependent-lookup

Given some code like in the following example:

```
class MyClass;

class Injector {
    /**
     * @brief MyClass addition.
     */
    friend MyClass operator+(MyClass a, MyClass b) { ... }
};

class MyClass: private Injector {};
```

How can I make doxygen include the documentation of `operator+()` on the documentation page of the MyClass class? Functionally it clearly belongs there. Is there some general way to make doxygen document functionality available through ADL?

A useful example in the real world: I'd like doxygen to include operators provided by the base classes in `boost/operators.hpp`.

Answer (score 2):

The `/relates` tag was designed for something close to that.

```
class MyClass;

class Injector {
    /**
     * @brief MyClass addition.
     * @relates MyClass
     */
    friend MyClass operator+(MyClass a, MyClass b) { ... }
};

class MyClass {};
```

This won't put the documentation on the *same page*, but will produce a "related functions" section on that same page, which links to the function.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdrelates

Comment: This does seem to be a straightforward approach, however it does not work in the case of `boost/operators.hpp`. How can I include documentation when the injector class is part of an external codebase?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work with the provided example. Doxygen keeps putting the docs with `Injector` (under the related section).